# sed /RegEx/,~N format address

Tags: sed

```
$ sed '/b/,~8 d' a-i.txt
```

I know what it does. But, they say "a multiple of 8" for ~8. Why is it expressed as "a multiple of 8"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/b/,~8` matches lines starting with a line containing `b` and continuing until a line is reached whose line number is a multiple of 8

From `man sed`:

> `addr1,~N`
>    Will match `addr1` and the lines following `addr1` until the next line whose  input line number is a multiple of `N`.

#### Examples

This prints any line which contains `5` and all following lines up to and including the next line whose line number is a multiple of 8:

```
$ seq 14 | sed -n '/5/,~8 p'
5
6
7
8
```

This prints from a line containing 14 to the next line whose line number is a multiple of 8:

```
$ seq 22 | sed -n '/14/,~8 p'
14
15
16
```

This deletes all lines starting with a line matches `5` and ending with the next line whose line number is a multiple of 8:

```
$ seq 10 | sed '/5/,~8 d'
1
2
3
4
9
10
```

#### Similar but different

This prints the fourth line and every eigtht line thereafter:

```
$ seq 22 | sed -n '4~8 p'
4
12
20
```

This prints a line matching `4` and the next three lines which follow:

```
$ seq 13 | sed -n '/4/,+3 p'
4
5
6
7
```

Comment: What do you mean with "a multiple of 8"?? It is just line 8, isn't it??

Comment: @Smile Or line 16, or line 24, etc.  I just added an example to show it printing up to line 16.

Comment: How do you write the examples and results like that? Is it just working if I click the "code" and write the $ sed 10 ..., then the result is automatic?? I'm just curious. You seems to be fast for editting your post.

Comment: @Smile I am copying-and-pasting from a terminal.  So I type, say, `seq 22 | sed -n '4~8 p'` into a terminal, press enter, and copy-and-paste the results to here.  Once I get here, I need to indent it by four spaces.  I do that by  highlighting it and typing Ctrl-K.